# org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets, dao

I'm learning javaEE. Before I put the annotation `OneToMany` and `ManyToOne` is everything working well. But then I see this error:

> INFO: HHH000327: Error performing load command :
>   org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given
>   identifier exists: [app.web.landingpage.object.Category#28]
>   getIndexPost org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the
>   given identifier exists: [app.web.landingpage.object.Category#28]

I can't select all information on db or insert. I use pattern DAO, Hibernate

**Category**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="CATEGORY")
    public class Category {

        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "ID", insertable=false, nullable=false)
        private int id;

        @Column(name="NAMECAT") 
        private String nameCat;

        @Column(name="INDEX") 
        private boolean index;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "category")
        private Set<Posts> post;
//then get and set
```

**Posts**

```
@Entity(name="Posts")
@Table(name="POSTS")
public class Posts implements java.io.Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="NAMEPOST", nullable = false) 
    private String namePost;

    @Column(name="TEXT", nullable = false) 
    private String text;

    @Column(name="IDCAT", nullable = false, insertable=false, updatable=false) 
    private int idCat;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Category category;
//then get and set
```

*interface* **CategoryDao**

```
public interface CategoryDao {
    public Collection getAllCategory();
}
```

*interface* **PostDao**

```
public interface PostDao {
   public Collection getIndexPost();
}
```

**CategoryDaoImpl**

```
public Collection getAllCategory() {
        Session session = null;
        List categoris = new ArrayList<Category>();
        try{
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            categoris = session.createCriteria(Category.class).list();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("getAllCategory "+ e);
        }finally{
            if(session != null && session.isOpen())
                session.close();
        }
        return categoris;
    }
```

**PostDaoImpl**

```
public Collection getIndexPost() {
        List<Posts> posts = null;
        Session session = null;
        try{
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            SQLQuery q = (SQLQuery) 
                    session.createSQLQuery("select p.* from posts p join category c on c.index=1");
            q.addEntity(Posts.class);
            posts = q.list();
        } catch(Exception e) { outputError("getIndexPost", e);
        } finally{ closeSession(session); }
        return posts;
    }
```

And this **servlet** outputs category and posts

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            try{
//get all category
                Collection allcategory = Factory.getInstance().getCatDAO().getAllCategory();
//get all post
                Collection allpost = Factory.getInstance().getPostDAO().getIndexPost();

                request.setAttribute("allcategory", allcategory);
                request.setAttribute("allpost", allpost);

                request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response); 
            } catch(Exception e) { 
                System.out.println(e);
            } finally{
                if(session!=null && session.isOpen())
                    session.close();
            }
```

---

**UPD:**

now output information fine, but i cant add in **posts** column **idCat**
before i add posts like this:

```
    String[] catarrayid = request.getParameterValues("eachcat");//get cat what user use
            String textpost = request.getParameter("textpost"); //text post
            String namepost = request.getParameter("namepost"); //name post

            if(!textpost.isEmpty() && !namepost.isEmpty() && catarrayid!=null) {
//open session              
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
                session.beginTransaction();

                Posts post = new Posts();
//this value take id category               
int id = 0;
                for(String s : catarrayid) {
                    id = Integer.parseInt(s);
                }

//create post object 
                post.setnamePost(namepost);
                post.setText(textpost);
//this i add in table post value idCat              
post.setIdCat(id);

                try{
//and i add
                    Factory.getInstance().getPostDAO().addPost(post);
                    response.sendRedirect("indexadmin");
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }finally{
                    if(session!=null && session.isOpen())
                        session.close();
                }
```

but now i change **Posts** like this

```
@Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="NAMEPOST", nullable = false) 
    private String namePost;

    @Column(name="TEXT", nullable = false) 
    private String text;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "IDCAT", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Category category;
```

and i dont know how add in post value idCat. In table post(id, namePost, Text, idCat). Category(id, nameCat)
I try but not success

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your mapping makes no sense. A category has several posts, but the post's ID, which uniquely identifies the post, is (according to your mapping) also the ID of the category it belongs to:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Category category;
```

You need some CATEGORY_ID column in Post, and that column should be the JoinColumn of the ManyToOne association.

Comment: Don't update this already answered, and already accepted question. Ask another, separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing referential integrity? Does your Category table contain rows where CategoryId has a value but that value doesn't exist in the id column of the Post table? If there are rows like that, delete them (they're corrupt), add referential integrity (foreign key from Category.postId to post.id), and try again